# Nonsensical values of loaded and total in AJAX file upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to build a progress bar for multiple files drag and drop upload by combining code from [tutorial on multiple files drag and drop uploading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqSlVvKvvjQ) and [tutorial on progress bar uploading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg).

Javascript part is:

```
var dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");

function updateProgress(e){
  document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = e.loaded + " of " + e.total;
}

function upload(files){
  var formData = new FormData(),
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      x;
  for(x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
    formData.append("file[]", files[x]);
  }
  xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
  xhr.open("post", "upload.php");
  xhr.send(formData);
}    

dropzone.ondrop = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.className = "dropzone";
  upload(e.dataTransfer.files);
}

dropzone.ondragover = function(){
  this.className = "dropzone dragover";
  return false;
}

dropzone.ondragleave = function(){
  this.className = "dropzone";
  return false;
}
```

And `upload.php` is simply:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"][0]))
  foreach($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $position => $name)
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$position], "uploads/".$name);
?>
```

For start, before making actual progress bar, I just want to show the number of uploaded and total bytes. However, function `updateProgress` doesn't get called if `upload.php` echoes nothing and otherwise (e.g. if I add `echo "something";`) `e.loaded` and `e.total` are small numbers of same value, unrelated to file size.

File upload itself works fine, even with large files (few hundred MBs). With large files, I've noticed that function `updateProgress` is called only once - after the upload is complete.

Why is this event handling behaving like this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting a progress handler for download, to set one for upload use

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
```